# A very complex combinations task that has been bugging me for 7 months

Tags: math, combinations, combinatorics

Some seven months ago I went to a job interview at a very big company. They gave me this task to solve, and for the past 7 months I can't seem to be able to find a solution.

---

**Here is the task:**
Some database has A entries. How many combinations (without repetition) with B amount (B < A) elements made out of A are there, that for any given B (contained in those A) different elements always contain at least X% of C entries (C < B) out of B given (C/B)? Include pattern for obtaining all of them. In short, we need:

1. Formula for calculation of how many combinations satisfy the above conditions
2. Formula for listing all of them. (any programming language or just detailed descriptive and any format)

*Note:* Both are mandatory, as those need to be set in a separate table in db.

---

**After 2 hours of being totally clueless I was given a simplified version:**
Some database has 50 entries. How many combinations (without repetition) with 9 elements made out of those 50 are there, that for any given 9 different elements (contained in those 50) always contain at least 15% of 6 entries out of given 9 (6/9)? Include pattern for obtaining all of them. In short, we need:

1. Formula for calculation of how many combinations satisfy the above conditions
2. Formula for listing all of them. (any programming language or just detailed descriptive and any format)

*Note:* Both are mandatory, as those need to be set in a separate table in db.

---

**Edit:** To explain further. Let us say the result of (1.) is D possible subsets (combinations without repetition) with 9 elements from A. And some user of the database (or software using it) enters random 9 elements (from |A| = 50 set). This always needs to result in, that at least 15% of those D subsets has 6 out of 9 that user entered. 
It doesn't matter how many of those D has 1/9, 2/9, 3/9, 4/9, 5/9, 7/9, 8/9 and 9/9, the only thing that matters is that 15% and above have 6/9, for any 9/50 entered. Oh and D needs to be the minimal possible.

**Edit2:** Even further. Example: Set of A=50 entries is given. We need minimal amount of possible combinations/subsets without repetition with B=9 elements from those 50, that satisfy the following: When a user enters random 9 entries, 15%+ of resulting subsets must have 6 out of 9 that user entered. And the resulting subset must be uniform for any 9 that user can enter.

---

And I still failed. And I am still clueless of how to solve something like this.

Comment: I don't get the purpose of the "at least X% of C entries" part. So I have a set of possible combinations. Apparently, every combination must fulfill this constraint. Are the C entries a previously specified set? Then 15% of 6 would be at least 1 entry. So every combination must contain at least 1 element from the set of C entries? Is that correct?

Comment: Added an edit that hopefully explains a bit more...

Comment: That edit made it even more confusing. Can you try to write the specification down in a formal way that shows the relation of all included sets and numbers?

Comment: Ehm.. One possible minimal set of combinations that satisfies the given constraint is the one-element set with the set of input elements that were entered by the user. Isn't it?

Comment: Gawd, how can a one-element set have 6 entries out of 9 entered?
We need 9-element entries, that have 6/9 that user entered. It's like playing a bingo where jackpot is 9 strikes, but we want to always have 15% of those with 6 strikes, not sure how else I can simplify.

Comment: The result is always a set of sets. Assume that the user provided the numbers `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`, then one minimal set of combinations is the set `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}`. This set contains one element (the provided input set) and 100% of the entries contain at least 6 out of the provided 9 elements.

Comment: if a user enters {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} We want a set of sets like this {{1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,13}, ...{4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}...} , but 15% of these sets need 6/9 that user entered, the rest 75% are not important for {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, but they need to cover any possible 9 numbers to give 15% of 6/9 strikes.

Comment: What about the minimality? The set will be minimal if we don't add any other combinations that are not from `{1, 2, ... 9}`. This set will have 100% valid entries.

Comment: Like I've said minimal for any combo of 9. Meaning same set of sets for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 etc.
OK, let us say this set {{1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,13}, ...{4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}...} has 1000 subsets. By 15% I mean 150 of those have 6/9 for any given 9 numbers from 1 to 50. So we don't need all possible combos, just need to make the big set that can always guarantee that 15% of it's subsets has 6/9. I did say this is a very complex task. So our resulting set of subsets must have same amount of 6/9 strikes for any combo of 9 numbers we enter

Comment: can you explain 'contain at least X% of C entries (C < B) out of B given (C/B)'? what is C, a subset of B or another separate but overlapping set?

Answer (score 1):

I explain the simplified version: Let's name your database A, with |A|=50 elements in it. Now 6 elements of these 50 are special somehow and we want to keep track of them. We call the set of these 6 elements C.

Now to our job: We should count all subsets X of A with exactly 9 elements and at least 15% of their elements should come from C. Since 15% of 9 is 1.35 we need at least 2 elements of C in our sets X.

We know that there are binomial(50,9)=2505433700 subsets of A with 9 elements. Now lets count how many of them **violate** your criteria: there are 44 elements in A which are not in C, so there are binomial(44,9) subsets of A that contain no elements from C. Next we count how many 9-element-subsets of A contain exactly one element of C: We take a random 8-element-subset from A without C and put exactly one element from C to it, so we get 6*binomial(44,8) possibilities.

Now we can write our result, by taking **all** 9-element-subsets from A and subtracting those, that violate your criteria:
  binomial(50,9) - binomial(44,9) - 6*binomial(44,8) = 733107430.

Ok... now we know how much there are. But how do we list them?
Let's use some pseude-code to do it:

```
AminC := setminus(A,C)

for j in 2..6 do
    for X1 in subsets(C, j) do
        for X2 in subsets(AminC, 9-j) do
            print(setadd(X1,X2))
```

This algorithm yields an alternative way of counting your sets:

binomial(6,2)*binomial(44,7) +...+ binomial(6,6)*binomial(44,3)=733107430.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Trying to understand this, but I think that I was unclear so it led to misunderstanding. C is the amount of entries from B. As stated in edit.
Database has A=50 entries. Now we need all combinations that have B=9 entries out of those 50, but with the following rule:
User enters random 9 entries from those 50, 15%+ of combinations in our resulting subset of combinations (without repetition) must have 6 out of 9 that user entered. Which means our resulting subset needs to be uniform for any 9 entries entered.